# Python VBA-like left()

Tags: python, django

I've been looking around but don't see anything similar to what I'm looking for.  Within a django site I want to add some code that looks at a values furthest left (or the first) character in a variable (which is populated by a DB query), and if it's a particular letter or number, do something with said variable.  How can I do this?

Comment: `if my_string.startswith('a'):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checks if the first letter in `mystring` is `'a'` or `'b'`.

```
if mystring[0] in ('a', 'b'):
    # whatever
```

Use slicing to test for longer substrings:

```
if mystring[:3] in ('abc', 'def', '987'):
    # whatever
```

Alternatively you can use `str.startswith()`:

```
if mystring.startswith(('SUBTOTAL', 'TOTAL')):
    # whatever
```

Comment: Thanks!!  Do you know of a good way to iterate through the English alphabet using this method?

Comment: In the slicing bit, I think you either want `mystring[:3]` or `('ab', 'de', '98')`.  I.e., the range needs to match the length of the match strings.

Comment: @jcfollower: I spend too much time coding in a language that does indexes wrong. Thanks for catching that.